# Should I store strings directly or their numeric tokens in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I can't decide which way to save event information to elasticsearch. The information is stored in mysql, and since I want to make them filterable, I've decided to use elasticsearch to index the events. Each of the fields have a limited number of options, but multiple options are allowed. Should I store the information directly like this:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Event A",
   "type":"Training,Workshop,Meeting",
   "industrialSector":"Energy,Transport",
   "country":"China"
   // + 80 fields alike
}
```

Or use some backend work to turn the string values into numeric tokens before saving to elasticsearch:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Event A",
   "type":"1 3 5",
   "industrialSector":"2 3",
   "country":"7"
   // + 80 fields alike
}
```

There will be a map object to reference the field options before saved or after fetched:

```
let options = 
{
    type:{
        Training:1,
        Fair:2
        Workshop:3,
        Brokerage:4
        Meeting:5
    },
    industrialSector:{
       Tech:1
       Energy:2
       Transport:3
    }
}
```

The first one requires less work, but does it perform slower and require more diskspaces than the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second solution has no benefits. I would just store the options as an array:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Event A",
   "type":["Training","Workshop","Meeting"]
   "industrialSector":["Energy","Transport"]
   "country":"China"
   // + 80 fields alike
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have been switching between these two solutions and couldn't decide which one. I'm seriously considering your suggestion. However, order is also important in some fields, so I'd opt to storing string instead of array. Is extra diskspace the only downside of storing string directly  compared to my second solution?

Comment: @RedGiant yes the source document (the document you sent to elasticsearch) will be stored on disk, you can disable this or enable compression. So I think 99% of the use cases its really no problem. If the order is important, my array should be not working, I think a text field could be solution.